# Shortcut to create to-do items in my to do list

Tags: shortcut

I am trying to create a fast way to create items in my to-do-list and I was hoping I could find a way to:

- Open Spotlight search(<kbd>Command</kbd> <kbd>Space</kbd>)
- Write some text for a new item in the search bar
- Click <kbd>Return</kbd>
- Update a file somewhere where I am storing my to do list by appending the text I typed.

Any creative alternative well accepted